# How to insert date/time in Mysql through c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to insert some data in a Mysql table from c#.
I have three fields (one of the date and two of the time) and I need to get the actual date and time.
But I have problems with the insertion in the data and time fields. The data field has 0000-00-00 and the time field 2019-04-24 00:00:00. I don't have any problem with the other fields.

I have tried ToString() with his different options, the TryParse and different solutions that I have seen on this page but none of them works and is not exactly what I need.

I let you my code:

```
    public static int SignEntry(MySqlConnection connection, string nif)
    {
        int ret;
        int active = 1;

        DateTime timeNow= DateTime.Now;
        timeNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

        DateTime dateNow= DateTime.Today;
        dateNow.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD");

        string query= String.Format("INSERT INTO entries(id,nif,active,date, entry_time, out_time) VALUES " +
            "(0,'{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}',null)", nif, active, dateNow, timeNow);

        MessageBox.Show(query);

        MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

        ret= com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return ret;
    }
```

I only need to insert actual data and actual time (when I call the method) in the entries table with date and time format (not string) but I don't know how can I do it

Thanks for helping!!

Comment: Use Parameters always. `String.Format`/interpolation wont protect you from injection or many other Bad Things.  If the DB columns are date there is no reason to convert to string and `"YYYY-MM-DD"` is not a legal format

Comment: _timeNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss");_ and the following _dateNow.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD");_ don't do what you think. They return a string with the format required but you don't get this result in a destination variable. It seems that you think you could change a datetime _format_ but a datetime variable has no format, it is just a number of ticks elapsed from a conventional starting point. As already explained you should use parameters not strings when creating sql commands

Comment: Yeah, I read it about parameterized queries but I don't fully understand it. Can you please give me an example of how can I do it? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Parameterized query replacing your string concatenation should be

```
 string query= @"INSERT INTO entries(nif,active,date, entry_time) 
                 VALUES (@nif, @active, @d, @e)";
 MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
 com.Parameters.Add("@nif", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nif;
 com.Parameters.Add("@active", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = active;
 com.Parameters.Add("@d", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dateNow;
 com.Parameters.Add("@e", MySqlDbType.Time).Value = timeNow;
 ret= com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also note that if *id* is an autoincrement column then you don't need to pass it in the query as well for column that should receive null values.

Notice how the query text is more simple to understand now and how all the parameters are specified with the datatype expected in the database table.

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Format("insert into `tablea`(`datetime`) values('{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}');", date);
```

or

```
string.Format("insert into `tablea`(`datetime`)values('{0}');", date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```